# How to total two int values from two different activities in 3rd?

Tags: java, android

I have a button with setText value set to 0 on activity created. It's 0 cause I total two int values, valueA and valueB that are 0 at game start. After another activity ends my valueA is now set to some public static int value in ActivityClassA, lets say 100. I need now when that activity ends to change that 0 value to new valueA+valueB value,100 + 0 = 100. I guess I should do this in onResume method, so I placed it there, and that's working fine.

```
button.setText("" + ActivityClassA.valueA + ActivityClassB.valueB);
```

But now I have activity2 starting and after that activity ends I have public static int valueB in ActivityClassB that's lets say 500. Now I need to update that sum value that is valueA+valueB to be 100+500=600. But now, my sum value is 500. And that's my problem.

I always get last set value as a total. If I start first ActivityB and then A, I would get total of 100.

Comment: Have a look at methods `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` in `Activity` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `startActivityForResult` to start your ActivityClassA and ActivityClassB and then use `onActivityResult` to display the result.  Your structure should be something like the following.

In main activity:

```
private static int ACT_A = 1;
private static int ACT_B = 2;

private int resultA = 0;
private int resultB = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
    ...
    myTextView.setText("" + (resultA + resultB));
    ...
}
```

Start each of ActivityClassA and ActivityClassB as:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityClassA.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ACT_A);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityClassB.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ACT_B);
```

In your ActivityClassA and ActivityClassB, you'll have a code like this:

```
int curScore;
...
Intent resp = new Intent();
resp.putExtra("score", curScore);
setResult(1, resp);
finish();
```

Finally, in your main activity, you'll have method `onActivityResult`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int respCode, Intent i) {
    if(respCode == 1) {
        switch(reqCode) {
            case ACT_A: resultA = i.getIntExtra("score", resultA);
                        break;
            case ACT_B: resultB = i.getIntExtra("score", resultB);
                        break;
        }
        myTextView.setText("" + (resultA + resultB));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I get error at case ACT_A and ACT_B...case expressions must be constant expressions. So i changed them to final. Is that OK?

Comment: Also, you said: "Start each of ActivityClassA and ActivityClassB as:"....well I get there error too. It says I should add argument to match argument 'Intent(Context, class<?>). Should I use 'this'?

Comment: @marjanbaz Sorry, my mistake.  I missed the first parameter to call `new Intent` - it should be `new Intent(this, ActivityClassA.class)`.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Also, is it OK to use public static int curScore; instead of just int curScore? I need it from another class to be able to see it.

Comment: Using static members, while may work, isn't a good idea. You should _never_ use static members for exchanging info between classes and always use proper interfaces.

Comment: I don't think there is need to myTextView.setText("" + (resultA + resultB)); in onCreate method. You did it twice. It works perfectly without it in onCreate method, only in onActivityResult.

Comment: @marjanbaz The only reason for it in `onCreate` is to ensure that the initial value is set correctly.  I don't know where the initial values are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Intent`s and `onActivityResult` to share data between activites. Using static values for this kind of stuff is not the best option.

Comment: I tried passing int values with intent but that did not work. How to use onActivityResult in my case?